# Light Sensor Error Unknown Code (Login & Register) Android App

Tags: java, android, light-sensor

So I'm having trouble figuring out what the bug is in my program.
Hard part is that it does not display an evident error.

In my home page, there are two buttons (Login & Register). When I press either one of them, I get the error "Unfortunately app has stopped"

I thought I was having a null pointer exception issue because that is what I always get when encountering the "Unfortunately app has stopped" error. However, if I try to check on the Android Monitor, I'm getting the Light Sensor Error Code (no idea what that is).

Here's my code:

Login

```
package com.example.rubybajet.tara;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        Button btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btn_login.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        TaraApp2 app = (TaraApp2) getApplication();
                        String validUsername = app.getAppUserUsername();
                        String validPassword = app.getAppUserPassword();

                        EditText edtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_username);
                        EditText edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);

                        String enteredUsername = edtUsername.getText().toString();
                        String enteredPassword = edtPassword.getText().toString();

                        if (enteredUsername.equals("")) {
                            loginToast();
                            return;
                        }

                        if (enteredUsername.equals(validUsername) && enteredPassword.equals(validPassword)) {
                            Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Category.class);
                            launchIntent.putExtra("USERNAME", edtUsername.getText().toString());
                            launchIntent.putExtra("PASSWORD", edtPassword.getText().toString());
                            startActivity(launchIntent);
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                }
        );

        Button btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        EditText edtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
                        EditText edtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);
                        EditText edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);
                        EditText edtCompany = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_company);
                        EditText edtContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);


                        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);

                        launchIntent.putExtra("USERNAME", edtUsername.getText().toString());
                        launchIntent.putExtra("PASSWORD", edtPassword.getText().toString());
                        launchIntent.putExtra("COMPANY", edtCompany.getText().toString());
                        launchIntent.putExtra("CONTACT", edtContact.getText().toString());
                        launchIntent.putExtra("NAME", edtName.getText().toString());

                        startActivity(launchIntent);

                        return;
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    private void loginToast() {
        EditText edtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_username);
        EditText edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);


        String usernameStr = edtUsername.getText().toString();
        String passwordStr = edtPassword.getText().toString();

        if (usernameStr.isEmpty()) {
            edtUsername.setError("Must enter username");

        }
        else if (passwordStr.isEmpty()) {
            edtPassword.setError("Must enter password");
        }
    }
}
```

Register

```
package com.example.rubybajet.tara;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import static android.R.attr.bitmap;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String mName = "";
    private String mUsername = "";
    private String mPassword = "";
    private String mCompany = "";
    private String mContact = "";

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    ImageView imageView;
    Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


        Intent recvdIntent = getIntent();

        mName = recvdIntent.getStringExtra("NAME");
        mUsername = recvdIntent.getStringExtra("USERNAME");
        mPassword = recvdIntent.getStringExtra("PASSWORD");
        mCompany = recvdIntent.getStringExtra("COMPANY");
        mContact = recvdIntent.getStringExtra("CONTACT");

       imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

        Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        registerToast();
                        submitUserData();
                        return;
                    }
                }
        );

        Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);
        upload.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        openGallery();
                    }
                });
        return;
    }


    private void openGallery() {
        Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap modifyOrientation(Bitmap bitmap, String image_absolute_path) throws IOException {
        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(image_absolute_path);
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                return rotate(bitmap, 90);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                return rotate(bitmap, 180);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                return rotate(bitmap, 270);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                return flip(bitmap, true, false);

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                return flip(bitmap, false, true);

            default:
                return bitmap;
        }
    }


    public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bitmap, float degrees) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(degrees);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    public static Bitmap flip(Bitmap bitmap, boolean horizontal, boolean vertical) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.preScale(horizontal ? -1 : 1, vertical ? -1 : 1);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    private void registerToast() {
        EditText edtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
        EditText edtCompany = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_company);
        EditText edtContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_contact);
        EditText edtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_username);
        EditText edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);


        String usernameStr = edtUsername.getText().toString();
        String passwordStr = edtPassword.getText().toString();
        String contactStr = edtContact.getText().toString();
        String companyStr = edtPassword.getText().toString();
        String nameStr = edtPassword.getText().toString();

        if (usernameStr.isEmpty()) {
            edtUsername.setError("Must enter username");
        }

        else if (passwordStr.isEmpty()) {
            edtPassword.setError("Must enter password");
        }

        else if (nameStr.isEmpty()) {
            edtName.setError("Must enter name");
        }

        else if (companyStr.isEmpty()) {
            edtCompany.setError("Must enter company");
        }

        else if (contactStr.isEmpty()) {
            edtPassword.setError("Must enter contact");
        }
        else
        {
            Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Register.this, Category.class);
        }
    }



    private void submitUserData() {
        EditText edtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
        EditText edtCompany = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_company);
        EditText edtContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_contact);
        EditText edtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_username);
        EditText edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_password);

        TaraApp2 app = (TaraApp2) getApplication();
        app.saveUserData(edtName.getText().toString(),edtUsername.getText().toString(),
                edtPassword.getText().toString(),
                edtCompany.getText().toString(),
                edtContact.getText().toString() );

        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUcnX.png)

Comment: There has been some developments and the error is now is the cannot cast issue.

Comment: Please do always post your logcat as **TEXT**.